# Azure Application gateway ARM template issue with pickHostNameFromBackendAddress and hostname in backendHttpSettingsCollection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-application-gateway

Getting issue in ARM template while configuring backendHttpSettingsCollection. I can not use pickHostNameFromBackendAddress for both condition (true, false ), If we select True then it is throwing eror for hostname, I tried applying json('null'), but still it is throwing the same  error.

Is there any way we can Implement both condition in same ARM template.

Template :

```
{
        "name": "backendHttpSettingsCollection",
        "count": "[length(parameters('backendHttpSettings'))]",
        "input": {
          "name": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].name]",
          "properties": {
            "port": 443,
            "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].pickHostNameFromBackendAddress]",
            "hostName": "[if(parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].pickHostNameFromBackendAddress, json('null') , parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].hostName)]",
            "protocol": "Https",
            "probeEnabled": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].probeEnabled]",
            "probe": {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/probes',  parameters('applicationGatewayName'), parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollection')].probe)]"
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Parameter :

```
 {
      "name": "https-test1",
      "hostName": "",
      "probeEnabled": true,
      "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": true,
      "probe": "slash-probe1"
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: @old_timer  ,  May I know the reason for your negative vote ? I am stuck with this issue please see you can help on this. I wanted to implement ARM with true and false value of pickHostNameFromBackendAddress in single template,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the same error. It cannot pass the template validation even if the null or blank value is assigned to `hostName`.

As a workaround, You can have a try wrapping all the properties in a parameter object. Define two object parameters for the true and false scenario. See below example:

```
 "parameters": {
               "pick": {
                  "type": "bool",
                  "defaultValue": true
               },
               "host": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "defaultValue": "leviCustom.com"
               },
            "pickFalse":{
                "type": "object",
                "defaultValue":{
                    "port": 443,
                    "protocol": "Https",
                    "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                    "hostName": "[parameters('host')]",
                    "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": false,
                    "requestTimeout": 20
                }
            },
            "pickTrue":{
                "type": "object",
                "defaultValue":{
                    "port": 443,
                    "protocol": "Https",
                    "cookieBasedAffinity": "Disabled",
                    "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": true,
                    "requestTimeout": 20
                }
            }
        },
```

---

```
"backendHttpSettingsCollection": [
                            {
                                "name": "LeviHttpSetting",
                                "properties": "[if(parameters('pick'),parameters('pickTrue'),parameters('pickFalse'))]"
                            }
```

Comment: This will not make a difference as when you pick  pickHostNameFromBackendAddress as true ARM will not allow you to use HostName property in template.  We can only  provide HostName when we have pickHostNameFromBackendAddress as false.

Comment: actually problem is this error :   "code": "ApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettingsHostNameFieldConflict",
        "message": "HostName field may only be specified if pickHostNameFromBackendAddress is set to false in context..          we can not specify HostName property if pickHostNameFromBackendAddress is set as true , even the null or blank value is not permitted

Comment: I see the problem. You can check out the workaround above.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken it as variable as I need to support more then one Item in array,

Answer (score 0):

taken Properties as variable like below :

```
"copy": [
  {
    "name": "backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost",
    "count": "[length(parameters('backendHttpSettings'))]",
    "input": {
      "name": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost')].name]",
      "properties": {
        "port": 443,
        "hostName": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost')].hostname]",
        "protocol": "Https",
        "probeEnabled": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost')].probeEnabled]",
        "probe": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/probes',  parameters('applicationGatewayName'), parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost')].probe)]"
        }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost",
    "count": "[length(parameters('backendHttpSettings'))]",
    "input": {
      "name": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost')].name]",
      "properties": {
        "port": 443,
        "pickHostNameFromBackendAddress": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost')].pickHostNameFromBackendAddress]",
        "protocol": "Https",
        "probeEnabled": "[parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost')].probeEnabled]",
        "probe": {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/probes',  parameters('applicationGatewayName'), parameters('backendHttpSettings')[copyIndex('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost')].probe)]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and used in application gateway properties as below :

```
"backendHttpSettingsCollection": "[if(variables('pickHostNameFromBackendAddress')[0], variables('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithoutHost') , variables('backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost'))]",
```

this is working for both conditions

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you share the whole template? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Getting the following Error: 
Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template variable 'backendHttpSettingsCollectionWithHost' is not valid: The language expression property 'hostname' doesn't exist, available
properties are 'name, port, protocol, cookieBasedAffinity, pickHostNameFromBackendAddress, affinityCookieName, requestTimeout, probe'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'.

This is because I do not always set the hostname. If I choose hostname: "" it will pick the configuration with hostname parameter.

Comment: HI @Erik , not able to post full template here, First block of code is part of variable, and last block is used in property.

Comment: You only have one backendHttpSettingsCollection per deployment? 
I have an array with combination of with and without hostname.
variables('pickHostNameFromBackendAddress')[0]; This only looks at the first one.